# Puppet powershell Error with Windows AD

Tags: windows, powershell, dns, active-directory, puppet-enterprise

I'm fairly new to puppet and still getting familiar with it.
I'm trying to install AD, promote the server to DC and create OU and some users with "jriviere/windows_ad" module (https://forge.puppet.com/jriviere/windows_ad).

I succeed in installing the AD but always fail when configuring forest (Promoting to DC) with the following error.

> Error: 'Import-Module ADDSDeployment; Install-ADDSForest -Force
>   -DomainName devops.local -DomainMode 6 -DomainNetbiosName devops -ForestMode 6 -DatabasePath c:\windows\ntds -LogPath c:\windows\ntds -SysvolPath c:\windo\sysvol -SafeModeAdministratorPassword (convertto-securestring 'P@ssw0rd' -asplaintext -force) -InstallDns'
>   returned 1 instead of one of [0] Error:
>   /Stage[main]/Windows_ad::Conf_forest/Exec[Config ADDS]/returns: change
>   from notrun to 0 failed: 'Import-Module ADDSDeployment;
>   Install-ADDSForest -Force-DomainName devops.local -DomainMode 6
>   -DomainNetbiosName devops -ForestMode 6 -DatabasePath c:\windows\ntds -LogPath c:\windows\ntds -SysvolPath c:\windows\sysvol -SafeModeAdministratorPassword (convertto-securestring 'P@ssw0rd' -asplaintext -force) -InstallDns' returned 1 instead of one of [0]
>
> Notice: /Stage[main]/Windows_ad/Anchor[windows_ad::end]: Dependency
>   Exec[ConfigADDS] has failures: true Warning:
>   /Stage[main]/Windows_ad/Anchor[windows_ad::end]: Skipping because of
>   failed dependencies

I can provide the parameters used but they are a lot and I don't want this thread to be long for no reason.

No matter what parameters I change it still fails, I tried promoting it manually or with power-shell script of the VM itself and I succeeded without any problems.

Any help is appreciated as I'm beginning to give up.

Comment: Your error message is pretty clear.. `Install-ADDSForest -Force -DomainName devops.local -DomainMode 6 -DomainNetbiosName devops -ForestMode 6 -DatabasePath c:\windows\ntds -LogPath c:\windows\ntds -SysvolPath c:\windo\sysvol -SafeModeAdministratorPassword (convertto-securestring 'P@ssw0rd' -asplaintext -force) -InstallDns' returned 1 instead of one of [0]`

Comment: yes I'm aware that its clear, and as I said I tried the same steps with the same parameters with power-shell and it succeeded.

My question is why is it failing with puppet?

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://www.petri.com/managing-windows-server-with-puppet-part-7-installing-active-directory) and worked fine. First run `puppet module install puppetlabs-dsc` on Puppet master